# GBPing | get result synchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c, ping

I'm using GBPing to ping several IPs calling a method.
The problem is that GBPing gives result by delegate methods and I don't know how to monitor delegate results from another thread.

Example code, loop for pinging N hosts.

```
for(int i=1; i< pow(2,(32-netmask)) -1; i++){
    ph[i] = [[PingHelper alloc] init];
    //compose IPv4
    NSString *finalAddr = [IPHelper composeIPv4:addrs[0] netmask:netmask host:i];
    [ph[i] ping:finalAddr semaphore:NULL];
}
```

PingHelper call.

```
self->ping = [[GBPing alloc] init];
self->ping.host = host;
self->ping.delegate = self;
self->ping.timeout = 1.0;
self->ping.pingPeriod = 0.9;

[self->ping setupWithBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) { //necessary to resolve hostname
    if (success) {
        //start pinging
        [self->ping startPinging];  
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"failed to start");
    }
}];

//while(!finished);
return result;
```

Thanks,
Oscar